# How to pass an interface from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli

Is there a possibility to pass an Interface from C# to C++.

```
interface IMessage
{
     DoSomething();
}
```

I would like pass an instance of IMessage to C++ code and call "DoSomething" from there.

Comment: Unless this is Managed C++; you would have to use COM marshaling to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean unmanaged c++, then you can create a COM interface from a C# interface by using the COMVisible attribute i.e.

```
[Guid("<a guid>")]
[ComVisible(true)]
interface IMessage
{
     DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the original asker tagged the question C++/CLI, I assume that's what he wants to target.

To pass a C# interface to C++/CLI, just declare the C++/CLI method to take the interface as a parameter. Be sure to specify the `^`, because interfaces must be passed by handle. Don't forget to edit the project properties for the C++/CLI project to reference whatever managed assembly contains IMessage.

```
public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    static void MyMethod(IMessage^ message)
    {
        message->DoSomething();
    }
};
```